# Static checks error:avoid instantiating new objec in loop

Tags: java

I have the following loop and I got PMD static check message :avoid instantiating new object in loop
Voc is constructor .
I need to create new instance in every loop ,there is a way to that in different way?

```
for (AnnoValue currValue : collection.getValues())
{

Voc(termName, this.nameSpace, this.alias);

}
```

Comment: What is currValue for? You are not using it at all?

Comment: yes this is part of the code

Answer (score 0):

First ensure is there anyway you could reuse this Voc instance for each iteration. In that case, move this instance creation out of the loop and possibly clear the state information at the start of the loop.

```
Voc vocInst = new Voc();
vocInst.setNamespace(this.nameSpace);
vocInst.setAlias(this.alias);
for (AnnoValue currValue : collection.getValues())
{
  vocInst.clear();
  vocInst.setTermName(termName); // I believe this is local variable and the rest of the parameters are instance variables.
  .....
  .....
}
```

Comment: This way, you got only one instance and overwrite a specific property, only. I think this was not intended.